# Simple object loader using sfml and open gl

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, .obj

I have created an obj loader and checked that the model loader function is working. it outputs all the relevant information for me to think that this isn't the problem im having. Everything seems to be working fine but the object just isnt drawing to the opengl window.

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

// tell OpenGL where the vertices are with glVertexPointer()
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);


//*************************************************************
// Set color and depth clear value
glClearDepth(1.f);
glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f,    0.f);

// Enable Z-buffer read and write
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

// Setup a perspective projection
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90.f, 1.f, 1.f, 500.f);
```

Here is where I think could be the problem.
or here..

```
if((float)Clock.GetElapsedTime()>REFRESH_RATE){
        // Clear colour and depth buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        //glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -50.f);


        //draw the triangles with glDrawArrays() and then with       glDrawElements()
        Clock.Reset();
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()/3);

    }
```

Here is the model loader function...

```
bool ModelLoader(string fileName, vector<GLfloat>& vertices, vector<GLushort>& indices, vector<GLfloat>& normals)
GLushort ind1, ind2, ind3; // declaring gl variables and variables
GLfloat vertex[3];
GLushort texel[3];
GLfloat normal[3];
GLuint indvalue = 1;
fstream objectFile;
string dataLine;
stringstream mystream;
GLfloat x, y, z;
vertices.clear();
indices.clear();
vector<GLfloat> localVertices;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    vertices.push_back(0);
    cout << endl << "Vertices Pushed Back" << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    localVertices.push_back(0);
    cout << endl << "Local Vertices Pushed Back" << endl;
}

objectFile.open("objs/Cube.obj"); 
if (!objectFile.good()) // error checking to see if object file is loaded
    cout<<endl<<"Error: Could not load object "<<endl;

while (!objectFile.eof())
{
    getline(objectFile, dataLine,'\n'); // get line of the file
    mystream.clear(); // clear stream
    mystream.str(dataLine); // stream = dataline
    if (dataLine.empty()) // skip line if empty
    {
        cout << endl << " line is empty: Skipped line" << endl;
    }
    else if (dataLine[0] == 'v' && dataLine[1] == ' ') // if first char is v and second is space
    {
        mystream.ignore(2); // ignore the first two chars
        mystream >> x >> y >> z; // input local vertices to x, y and z
        localVertices.push_back(x); // push back each vertex
        localVertices.push_back(y);
        localVertices.push_back(z);
        printf("\nVertices: %f, %f, %f", x, y, z); // output for debugging
        cout << endl << "Local x, y and z vertices pushed back" << endl;
    }
    else if (dataLine[0] == 'f' && dataLine[1] == ' ') // if the first characted of the line is an f and the second is a space
    {
        cout << endl << "f found" << endl; // output for debugging
        cout << mystream.str() << endl;

        mystream.ignore(2); // ignore first two characters

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            cout << endl << mystream.str()<< endl;

            mystream >> vertex[i]; // put value of mystream into vertex i 
            cout << endl << vertex[i] << endl; // output for debugging 

            mystream.ignore(1);

            if (mystream.peek() == '/') // if the next char = /
            {
                mystream.ignore(1); // ignore that char
            }

            else
            {
                mystream >> texel[i]; // input  value from my stream into texel i
                cout << endl << texel[i] << endl;
                mystream.ignore(1);
            }
            // ****************************** //
            mystream >> normal[i];
            cout << endl << normal[i] << endl;
            // ****************************** //
        }

        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[0]* 3 + 0]); // x value  push back local vertices
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[0]* 3 + 1]); // y value 
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[0]* 3 + 2]); // z value 
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[1]* 3 + 0]); // x value 
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[1]* 3 + 1]); // y value 
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[1]* 3 + 2]); // z value 
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[2]* 3 + 0]); // x value 
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[2]* 3 + 1]); // y value 
        vertices.push_back(localVertices[vertex[2]* 3 + 2]); // z value 
        indices.push_back(indvalue); ++indvalue;  // push back indvalues 
        indices.push_back(indvalue); ++indvalue;
        indices.push_back(indvalue); ++indvalue;
        cout << endl << "vertices and indices pushed back" << endl;



    }

    mystream.clear(); // clear the stream
}
objectFile.close(); // close the file
cout << endl << "Function complete" << endl;
return true;
}
```

Comment: First, the obvious. Are you sure glDrawArrays is being called? There are so many things that could cause rendering to go wrong. First ensure your context and window are set up properly: if you set your clear color to, say, red and clear, do you see red?

Comment: Yes I have tested that the colour changes and the draw arrays does get called.

Comment: why are you only drawing 1/3 of your vertices? `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()/3);`